# Cypress tests not recognizing node_modules package types

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, tsconfig

I'm having trouble with my Cypress tests for my (Typescript) application recognizing types for package I've installed.  Here is my top-level directory structure:

```
cypress
node_modules
src
```

My `cypress/tsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["../src/*"]
    },
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017.string"],
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

In one of my spec files, I have the following imports:

```
import * as faker from 'faker';
import { DeepPartial } from 'utility-types';
```

The types for `faker` are defined in DefinitelyTypes (`@types/faker`) whereas the types for `utility-types` are included as `*.d.ts` files in that package.  The `faker` import has no problem, but the `utility-types` import is giving a *Cannot find module 'utility-types' or its corresponding type declarations.* error.

I've tried explicitly including the `*.d.ts` files from the node_modules directory to the `tsconfig.json` file under `compilerOptions.types`, `compilerOptions.typeRoots`, and `include` properties, but to no avail.

I also created "fake" (?) types like the following so it will compile:

```
declare module 'utility-types' {
  export type DeepPartial<T> = {};
}
```

This allows for the app to compile AND, at run-time, the packages are resolved so it appears the issue is with finding the types, not the modules themselves.

**Why is Cypress not finding the types for these packages?**

Comment: Try adding the following to your `.tsconfig`: ```"include": [
    "node_modules/cypress/types/index.d.ts",
    "node_modules/cypress/types/blob-util.d.ts",
    "node_modules/cypress/types/minimatch.d.ts",
    "node_modules/cypress/types/bluebird.d.ts",
    "cypress/**/*.ts"
  ]```

Comment: For reference, I looked at a sample repo with a working TS environment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/preprocessors__typescript-webpack/tsconfig.json

Comment: @RaghavKukreti I should have mentioned I tried the `include` tsconfig property in addition to `types` and `typeRoots`.  It does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set `moduleResolution` to `node`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#module-resolution-strategies

I have tried to import `utility-types` with this configuration: the import works, and test run correctly

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "strict": true,
      "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
      "paths": {
        "~/*": ["../src/*"]
      },
      "jsx": "react",
      "target": "es6",
      "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2017.string"],
      "types": ["cypress"],
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }
```